# How can I select the set of all nodes S which terminate a path from node A of class 'X' in which only the root and terminal node are of class 'X'?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Basically I'm looking for a way to select child "my-class" nodes even if they aren't directly children, and to not select any grandchildren "my-class" nodes given any "my-class" element.
For example, given "a" it would return "b", "g". given "b" it would return "c", "f", given "c" would return "d", "e", and "d" would return nothing. I can't seem to find a way to do this without traversing the DOM.

```
<div class="my-class" id="a">
  <div>
    <div class = "my-class" id="b">
      <div class = "my-class" id="c">
        <div class = "my-class" id="d">
        </div>
        <div class = "my-class" id="e">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class = "my-class" id="f">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class = "my-class" id="g">
        <div>
          <div>
            <div class="my-class" id="h">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I'm doing now is just traversing the DOM. If its "my-class" perform my operation, and if its not continue traversing down that part of the tree.

```
function traverse(element) {
  $(element).children(".my-class").trigger("my-event");
  var children = $(element).children(":not(.my-class)");
  for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
    traverse(children[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Given #a, shouldn't #h be included in the results? Since it's a descendant of #g that isn't a .my-class grandchild.

Comment: Also, #d and #e are always .my-class grandchildren regardless of which element you start from. Using a selector alone would always prevent them from being matched even when given #c (unless the `:scope` pseudo-class was implemented, in which case you could force them to match using `:scope > .my-class`). I suspect that DOM traversal is your best bet here.

Comment: Yeah, I kind of figured I'd have to do a DOM traversal here, was just hoping I was missing some selector or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recursively check each path in your DOM tree from the specified `$root`. The var `type` is anything you can put into the jQuery `in()` method, which includes selectors.

```
$.extend({findKids: function($el, type)
    {

        //define our recursive function
        var findPaths = function($el, $root, type)
        {
            //terminating step:
            //if the node is not the root, 
            //and is a type of "type", add 
            //it to the result set and return
            if ($el.is(type) && !$el.is($root))
            {
                $foundNodes = $foundNodes.add($el);
                return 1;
            }
            else
            {
                //recursive step:
                //look at the first generation of the element's children
                $el.children().each(function() {
                    //check in child to see if its of "type" or not
                    findPaths($(this), $root, type);
                });
            }
        }
        //store everything we find:
        $foundNodes = $();

        //call it once
        findPaths($el, $el, type);
        //found nodes will be in foundNodes
        return $foundNodes;
    }});
```

**Results**

```
console.log($.findKids($('#a'), '.my-class')); //#b, #g
console.log($.findKids($('#b'), '.my-class')); //#c, #f
console.log($.findKids($('#c'), '.my-class')); //#d, #e
console.log($.findKids($('#d'), '.my-class')); //empty
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var $children = $('.my-class').children();
```

[`.children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) will give you direct descendants for your selector.

> The .children() method differs from .find() in that .children() only travels a single level down the DOM tree while .find() can traverse down multiple levels to select descendant elements (grandchildren, etc.) as well.

Comment: Sorry, the code example didn't show up. Children isn't what I'm looking fore because they aren't necessarily direct children.

Comment: What do you mean "they aren't necessarily direct children." ?

Comment: See code example. Given "a", "b" and "g" would get selected, even though "g" isn't a direct child.